# How to store unique item in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to store unique value in my redux basket, but I am not able to store it.
I implemented this code I found from StackOverflow itself, but it is not working for me. I am still getting duplicate values stored in redux.

see this: [image]

Code:

```
    export const initialState = {
        basket: []
    }
    
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case 'Add_To_New':
                if (state.basket.indexOf(action.item) === -1) {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        basket:[...state.basket, action.item],
                    };
                }
                return state;
                default:
                    return state;
        }
    }
    
    export default reducer;
```

In the basket, I want to store this user only once if this already exists.  If I add the user again it should not store it but return the previously stored value.

Comment: What's the value of `action.item`?

Comment: Judging by the code: you are comparing concrete objects. Maybe something goes wrong there. Rather, compare by some property, e.x `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it's possible that the `indexOf` you're doing isn't matching to existing objects, possibly because the objects you're matching against have some different kind of data in it.

Assuming your `item` has some kind of id field on it, I'll use `id` for this example, you can also do something like

```
export const initialState = {
    basket: []
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'Add_To_New':
            if (!state.basket.map(item => item.id).includes(action.item.id) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    basket:[...state.basket, action.item],
                };
            }
            return state;
            default:
                return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Right we need to compare the `item.id` field but your solution is a little confusing, first, you are using `map` and then using `includes`. instead we can use `!state.basket.some(item => item.id === action.item.id)`